# PostgreSQL CASE WHEN with operator returns null row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to generate the pay period value based on the current date. When I ran the below query, it returns correct pay period, but I got additional null row. How can I get rid of null row?

```
select  distinct case  when current_date >= to_date(begin_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy') 
    and current_date < to_date(end_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy') 
    then cast(regexp_replace(itc_pp, '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') as integer)-1  end AS current_pp
from    actacc.payperiod_conversion_all_years
```

Currently it returns:

```
1 null
2 18
```

I want to return only the 2nd row.

Comment: Unrelated, but: **never** store date values in a `varchar` (or `text`)  column. Always use a proper `date` column. And why do you store numbers in a `varchar` column as well? Those are two very bad design choices.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `case` logic to a `where` clause:

```
select (cast(regexp_replace(itc_pp, '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') as integer)-1) AS current_pp
from actacc.payperiod_conversion_all_years
where current_date >= to_date(begin_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy') and
      current_date < to_date(end_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy') ;
```

I removed the `select distinct`.  You don't have samples of your data, so it is unclear if it is necessary.  If it is you can add it back in.

Note that you should be storing dates using a proper date/time data types, not as strings.  If you did that, the conversion step would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `where` condition to filter rows:

```
select  distinct cast(regexp_replace(itc_pp, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g') as integer)-1 AS current_pp
from    actacc.payperiod_conversion_all_years
where current_date >= to_date(begin_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy') 
  and current_date < to_date(end_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy')
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to match empty strings just to replace them by empty strings again, so I've changed `*` to `+` in your regex.

Comment: Thank you for your point on regexp. I didn't want to use WHERE, but I'll use your solution. Your answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, You only defined the CASE for records belongs to-

```
current_date >= to_date(begin_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy')
AND current_date < to_date(end_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy')
```

As a result, all records out of that date range is returning NULL as you do not defined anything what if the date is out of that range. You can define a ELSE part for the record outside of that date range. The script can be as below-

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
       CASE
           WHEN current_date >= to_date(begin_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy')
                AND current_date < to_date(end_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy') 
                THEN CAST(regexp_replace(itc_pp, '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') AS INTEGER) - 1
            ELSE itc_pp 
            -- Here you can keep the original value or do some 
            -- adjustment as per requirement to keep sync in values data type. 
       END AS current_pp
FROM actacc.payperiod_conversion_all_years;
```

If you add the date filter condition in where clause, the script should be as below-

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT CAST(regexp_replace(itc_pp, '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') AS INTEGER) - 1 current_pp       
FROM actacc.payperiod_conversion_all_years
WHERE current_date >= to_date(begin_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy')
AND current_date < to_date(end_payperiod_date, 'mm/dd/yy');
```

Comment: My requirement is just to return the rows which meets the condition. I don't think I can use CASE and "do nothing" (skip the rows if null) in ELSE. I guess I have to use WHERE

Comment: yes, then use where and that case no use of CASE is required.